# Вычисление количества временны́х промежутков в диапазоне

Tags: javascript

Приведу реальный пример, так как переводить это в "синтетику" - только путать.

**Исходные данные**

1. В гостинице есть время завтрака - будние дни `06:00-10:00`, выходные `07:00-11:00`
2. Время заезда и выезда гостей всегда считается от начала часа

Задача определения сколько раз гость может позавтракать за все время проживания.

**Мое решение**

У меня получилось сделать только "почасовым" перебором. Вот мой код:

```js
function CountBreakfast(start, stop) {
  if (start >= stop) return 0;
  let hours = (stop-start)/3600000;
  let count = 0;           // количество подсчитанных завтраков
  let skip = false;        // подсчитали завтрак, ждем часа "незавтрака"?
  let holiday = false;     // для определения выходного дня
  
  for (let i=0; i<hours; i++) {
    let now = new Date(start.getTime()+(i*3600000));
    // определение выходного дня
    holiday = now.getDay() == 0 || now.getDay() == 6; 
    // определение попадания в диапазон завтрака
    let hour = now.getHours();
    let timeof = ( holiday && (hour >= 7) && (hour < 11)) ||
                 (!holiday && (hour >= 6) && (hour < 10));
    // подсчет завтрака
    if (skip && !timeof) {
      skip = false;
      continue;
    }
    if (!skip && timeof) {
      skip = true;
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

var start = new Date(2021,7,29,3);
var stop = new Date(2021,7,30,7);
var count = CountBreakfast(start,stop);
console.log('Завтраков: ' + count);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stkgzy3e/

**Вопросы**

1. Есть ли вариант это посчитать формулой, без перебора?
2. А правильно ли я считаю?

Comment: *Задача определения сколько раз гость может позавтракать за все время проживания.* А когда он "может позавтракать"? Если у него выезд в 06:00 четверга - успеет? касание-то есть... А вообще - тупо количество дней между (DATEDIFF минус один) плюс по единичке за первый и последний дни, если он в эти дни "может".

Comment: Странно, у меня 2021 август 30 03:00 - 2021 август 30 06:00 - считает правильно, нуль завтраков. А по идее, да - надо пробовать формулой.

Comment: >>  Если у него выезд в 06:00 четверга - успеет? << Тут все верно, ибо, выехав в 06:00, он уже считается "незаселенным". Поэтому завтракать он сможет только отдельным счетом, но не в общем счете за проживание.